# Retrieve results from combined conditions MySQL database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to retrieve a specific count based upon *two conditions*, namely

if `'Fieldname'='Centrum'` has the `'FieldValue'='Reinier de Graaf, Delft'` *combined* with `'Fieldname'='Participate`' has the '`FieldValue'='Ja'`.

Something like:

```
$database = JFactory::getDBO();
$database->setQuery("SELECT COUNT(`SubmissionId`) FROM #__rsform_submission_values WHERE (`FieldName`='Participate' AND `FieldValue`='Ja') AND (`FieldValue`='Reinier de Graaf Gasthuis, Delft')");
$formLayout = "Reinier de Graaf Gasthuis, Delft: <strong>".$database->loadResult()."</strong>";
```

However, in this case it does not give me the correct number. Probably I'm mixing some things up.

Comment: You're asking your database, if the column "FieldValue" holds the data 'Ja' and 'Reinier de Graaf Gasthuis, Delft' AT THE VERY SAME ROW. That simply can't be the case.

Comment: Hi Stefan, no I ask that the fieldname 'centrum' needs to have fieldvalue ' Reinier de Graaf'  and that a different fieldname 'participate' (so in another row but with same submissionId) needs to have fieldvalue 'ja'

Answer (score 2):

It never gives you correct results. You are doing like :

`FieldValue`='Ja' AND  `FieldValue`='Reinier de Graaf Gasthuis, Delft'

above is the error. you can use OR in one case

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be:

```
SELECT COUNT(`SubmissionId`) FROM #__rsform_submission_values 
WHERE `FieldName`='Participate' AND 
      (`FieldValue`='Ja' OR `FieldValue`='Reinier de Graaf Gasthuis, Delft');
```

This is because it is impossible to have a data with field value that holds two values at the same time. Or you better use the [INSTR function](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-instr-function.php) to check if the FieldValue contains the searched strings.:

```
SELECT COUNT(`SubmissionId`) FROM #__rsform_submission_values 
WHERE `FieldName`='Participate' AND 
      (INSTR(`FieldValue`,'Ja')>0 OR INSTR(`FieldValue`,'Reinier de Graaf Gasthuis, Delft')>0);
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I did not explain myself enough. The 'Centrum' needs to be 'Reinier de Graaf' AND the 'Participate' needs to be 'Ja' in order to get included in the count. Using your above string, it does not take the FieldName Centrum into account. Thank you so much for helping!